# How to get data from axios request?

Tags: axios, alpine.js

I'm having a problem with an axios GET request in my alpine component.
It always returns a Promise instead of the actual data.

The GET request sends an array of id's *(which is stores in localstorage)* to an API endpoint, where more data is loaded from the database for each of the id's. When testing this is Postman, it's working perfectly.
The problem happens when I'm trying to iterate the results with `x-for`. It fails because the request do not contain the actual data, but a *"Promise < pending >"*.

I've tried to call an aditional `.then` on my `getItems()` function but that still only returns the Promise instead of the data. I've also tried to use `async` and `await` but that doesn't work either.

Heres my full code:

**JS:**

```js
import axios from 'axios'
window.Spruce.store('my_store', {
  items: [],
}, true)
window.myComponent = function() {
  return {
    itemIds() {
      return this.$store['my_store'].items
    },
    getItems() {
      return axios.get('http://my-application.test/wp-json/my-api/images/?ids=' + this.itemIds()).then((response) => {
        return response.data
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    },
  }
}
```

**async await attempt**

```js
async getItems() {
  return await axios.get('http://my-application.test/wp-json/my-api/images/?ids=' + this.itemIds()).then((response) => {
    return response.data
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
},
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div x-data="myComponent()">
    <template x-for="item in getItems()">
        <div x-text="item.title"></div>
    </template>
</div>
```

Anyone know how I'm going to make `getItems()` return the actual data so I can use it in my `x-for` loop, in the HTML?

Comment: A quick search for _"alpine.js async data"_ resulted in this tutorial ~ https://blog.logrocket.com/getting-started-with-alpine-js/#buildinganimagegallerywithalpinejs

Comment: You are trying to iterate on a promise (getItems() returns a promise) which is a mistake. You need to store the results of getItems into a variable then iterate on that variable. Also I assume you should set the initial variable value to an empty array, but I haven't used alpine.js so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is it's returning the promise from the `axios` request.
We can solve it by assigning the results to the `$store` and for each for the items in `$store` as below,

```js
import axios from 'axios'
window.Spruce.store('my_store', {
  items: [],
}, true)
window.myComponent = function() {
  return {
    itemIds() {
      return this.$store['my_store'].items
    },
    getItems() {
      let vm = this;
      return axios.get('http://my-application.test/wp-json/my-api/images/?ids=' + this.itemIds()).then((response) => {
        vm.$store['my_store'].items = response.data; // assign it to items in the store
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    },
  }
}
```

Now we can do a for each for the items in the `$store`

```html
<div x-data="myComponent()">
    <template x-for="item in $store.my_store.items">
        <div x-text="item.title"></div>
    </template>
</div>
```

I used the `$store` since you have used it for state management/sharing, but its not nessacsary, we can even have a property directly in the component level and assign the results to it.